# C++ - how to push objects to std::stack of std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, stack, shared-ptr

I've got a problem with stack of shared pointers.

GameState.hpp:

```
class GameState : std::enable_shared_from_this<GameState>
{
public:
    virtual void update(float delta) = 0;
    virtual void render() = 0;
    virtual void handleInput() = 0;
protected:
    Game* mGame;
```

StatesManager.hpp:

```
class StatesManager
{
public:
    StatesManager();
    ~StatesManager();

    void pushState(std::shared_ptr<GameState> state);
    void changeState(std::shared_ptr<GameState> state);
    void popState();
    std::shared_ptr<GameState> peekState();
private:
    std::stack<std::shared_ptr<GameState> > mStates;
};
```

Here's how I'm trying to push:

```
statesManager.pushState(new StateSplash(this));
```

But that's gives me this error:

```
no suitable constructor exists to convert from "StateSplash *" to "std::shared_ptr<GameState>"
```

What's correct way of pushing object onto std::stack of std::shared_ptrs?
I want to use them, because it provides "garbage collector", which I need, because if I pop element from stack when object is C-like pointer, it doesn't call destructor.

Comment: `statesManager.pushState(std::shared_ptr<GameState>(new StateSplash(this)));`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You should post an answer and explain why *explicit*ly ;), rather than a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `StateSplash` is a child of `GameState`.

Your method accepts a `std::shared_ptr` and you are trying to pass a normal pointer into it. Your compiler does not know how to get from `StateSplash *` to `std::shared_ptr<GameStage>`.

You have to construct a `std::shared_ptr` by either

`statesManager.pushState(std::make_shared<GameState>(this));`

or

`statesManager.pushState(std::shared_ptr<GameState>(new StateSplash(this)));`